# My scraper throws error instead of downloading images

Tags: python, web-crawler

I've made a scraper to download images from a site. However, when i run this, it throws error showing: [raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403]. I used this method on other sites as well to scrape images but faced no issues. I can't figure out Why this error shows up and what is the workaround. Hope someone will look into it.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from lxml import html

def PictureScraping():
    url = "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//div[@class="movie-image"]')
    for title in titles:
        Pics = "https:" + title.xpath('.//img/@src')[0]
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(Pics, Pics.split('/')[-1])
PictureScraping()
```

Comment: It is `403` HTTP code, aka *Unauthorized*. You surely got spotted as crawler and so black listed. You have to play with proxy & user-agent http header to bypass this kind of behaviours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download images using the same web-scraping session you've used to get the initial page. Working code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html


def PictureScraping():
    url = "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/"
    with requests.Session() as session:
        response = session.get(url)

        tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
        titles = tree.xpath('//div[@class="movie-image"]')
        for title in titles:
            image_url = title.xpath('.//img/@src')[0]
            image_name = image_url.split('/')[-1]
            print(image_name)
            image_url = "https:" + image_url

            # download image
            response = session.get(image_url, stream=True)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                with open(image_name, 'wb') as f:
                    for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
                        f.write(chunk)

PictureScraping()
```

Comment: Oh my god! It works like magic. Thanks sir, alecxe for your effective solution.